# random access to buffer optimisation

Tags: c++, optimization, buffer

I have `colorBuffer Color[width*height]` (most likely 800*600)

and during rasterization I call:

```
void setPixel(int x, int y, Color & color)
{
    colorBuffer[y * width + x] = color;
}
```

It turns out that this random access to color buffer is really ineffective and slows my application down.

I think that it is caused the way I use it. I calculate some pixel (with rasterization algorithms) and call setPixel.
So I think my buffer is not in cache and this is the main problem. When trying to write into the whole buffer at once, it is much much faster.

Is there any way, how to optimize this?

**edit**

I do not use it to fill buffer with two for cycles.
I use it to paint "random" pixels.
eg when rasterize line I use it like

```
setPixel(10,10);
calculate next point
setPixel(10,11);
calculate next point
setPixel(next point)
...
```

Comment: Making it inline might also slow things up a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should try to be cache-friendly,
but the first thing I would do is find out what's taking time.

It's simple enough. Just pause it several times and see what it's doing.

If it's mostly in `calculate next point`, you should see what it's doing in there, because that's where the time is going.
(I assume you understand that by "in" I mean "on the stack".)

If it's mostly in `SetPixel`, when you pause it, look at the disassembly window.

If it's spending much time in the prologue/epilogue of the routine, it should be inlined.

If it's spending much time in the actual move instruction into `colorBuffer`, then you're hitting the cache issue.

If it's spending much time in the code for the index calculation `y * width + x`, then you might want to see if you could somehow use an initialized pointer that you step along.

If you fix anything, you should do it all again, because you may have uncovered another opportunity to speed it up further.

Comment: thank you. It is cache issue. The main problem is how to make it faster. Perhaps force buffer to stay in cache or something like that

Answer (score 2):

They way I see it, the access-pattern to the buffer depends in the order in which your algorithm processes the pixels. Can you not simply change that order so that it creates a sequential access-scheme to your buffer?

Comment: At least, can you sort the objects to be rasterized in top-to-bottom, left-to-right order, and then rasterize each object working in the same direction?

Comment: @Useless no i can not. I have to rasterize them as soon as I get one.

Comment: Why does it matter whether you rasterize "eagerly" (ie, as soon as called) so long as everything is done before the next display refresh, save to file, or whatever?  If that **is** the case, all you can do is try inlining `setPixel`, and try to make the `Color` object as small as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to notice is that the way you process your pixels makes a huge difference to speed. If you do

```
for (int x = 0; x < width;++x)
{
  for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
  {
    setPixel(x,y,Color());
  }
}
```

this will be really bad for performance because you're literally jumping around in memory width-wise (note that you do y*width + x).

If you simply change the order of processing to

```
for (int y = 0; y < height;++y)
{
  for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
  {
    setPixel(x,y,Color());
  }
}
```

you already should notice a performance gain as the processor now gets a chance to cache memory accesses (which it didn't before).

Furthermore you should check if you can determine that entire blocks of pixels will have the same color value before actually setting the memory. Then you can copy those constant color values block-wise to your image array which can save you also a good deal of performance.

Comment: @relaxxx Well I assume you are calculating the objects in a loop? Instead of determining the position for each color, it would be way more efficient if you'd scan the buffer with two nested loops and for each pixel position determine the color instead.

Comment: I can not do it like this. User can use it like `setColor` and `paintCircle` then another `setColor` and then `printLine`. I calculate circle points and write them with actual color. then calculate line points and calculate them with new actual color. I really do not see the way, how to fill color buffer afterwards

Comment: @relaxxx Well you can. This is how rasterizers work. See for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanline_rendering , http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/gr/resources/08-triangles.slides.pdf